# GitHub with TFS ALM

Tags: github, visual-studio, team-foundation-server, jira

Is it possible to use TFS Application Lifecycle Management features (ie, user stories, tasks, work items, gated commits, all the good stuff) against a repository stored in GitHub?

How would one go about setting up the configuration to do this?

The reason is pretty simple - we're using GitHub because work says we have to, we're using VS2015 with the GitHub plugin and to manage the backlog we're using..... Jira.  Which is terrible and lacks any form of integration or decent tracking.  My team would like to spike our project into TFS (visual studio online to begin with) so we can show our management a real improvement in tracking and traceability.

Comment: AFAIK this is what TFS online is all about.  Though we don't use the tracking features, they are there, and they look decent.

Comment: I'd be happy to use TFS Online (in fact, that would be the preference) but I can't move the repo out of Github.

Comment: @RichBryant why not? TFS online supports Git repositories. You could replace both Jira and GitHub with TFS online. If you absolutely *must* host your code on Github, you could set up a batch job on a schedule to push your TFS/Git repo up to GitHub once a week/day.

Answer (score 2):

You can.

You can keep your code in GitHub  and use both Build  and Release tools in TFS or VSTS. What  you loose is  the ability to link work items to code.  Everything else works just fine, including creating and managing work in the whole planning tools.

When you create a Build in the new build system you can select the  source as GitHub. From then on you are in TFS.

In addition you can have your code on both places. It's a little bit dirty, but you can have your code in Git inside of TFS and create a CI that pushes the code to GitHub. You would then get the best of both worlds...

Comment: Linking work items to code was really the intention.

Comment: Then you will need Git in TFS/VSTS as your primary. Developers work there, and then you can have an aurlyomated build, triggered by a checkin, to push to GitHub.

Comment: How would I go about doing that, with VSTS (as a demo)?